# Wrong coordinates after rotating, scaling and moving one image and sending the transform to other ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, rotation, transform

I'm manipulating an image (scale, position, rotation). Once that's done, the user is redirected to another viewcontroller where I'm loading the same image in the same position.

I'm sending the transform as a String from one viewcontroller to the other:

```
NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(self.myImage.transform)
```

But the image is not in the right position, it's slightly moved.

I've tried to send also the bounds, center, even the frame of the image along with the transform, but I'm not getting the identical position, scale and rotation of the original image.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure 'transform' holds all position information? what about frame, Layout constraints... A little more context / code would be helpful.

Comment: The transform is a matrix with 9 values. After applying it, the position is very close to the original one, but not identical. I tried to send and apply also the center of the image, the bounds and the frame without success. I've read I shouldn't send the translation in the transform, only scale and rotation, but I don't know how to separate it from that matrix.